# /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/ is not a symbolic link (Whole Folder)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, lib

I've seen several threads talking about the error of "/usr/lib/lib...so is not a symbolic link" that means that lib is not referred by the previous one, but this is different. 
it says THE WHOLE /usr/lib/ is not a symbolic link ... 
why does this happen?
I've got Ubuntu-16.04
Thanks in advance

Comment: Same problem here. Upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 did not solve it.

Answer (score 2):

1.use "ldconfig -v" to find that line(link name according to your own situation)：
ldconfig: /usr/lib/ is not a symbolic link

```
     -> libqmmpui.so.0.7.5
```

2.go to /usr/lib to remove that link file

*reference：https://bbs.archlinuxcn.org/viewtopic.php?id=2482

Comment: OMG thanks! This has been annoying me (albeit irregularly) for years!